# Rules loop through list and create nodes with custom title

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I'm using rules to create new nodes on 'After saving content of type' event.

To do so I loop through a list of type entity reference

```
Loop
Parameter: List: [node:field-childs]
List item: Current list item (list_item)
```

Inside the loop I  Create a new entity,

```
Create a new entity
Parameter: Entity type: Node, Content type: Attendance, Title: 
[node:field_childs], Author: [node:author]
Provides variables: CreateAttendancePage (basic_attendance_created)
```

Then I save the entity

```
Save entity
Parameter: Entity: [node], Force saving immediately: true
```

This will title all the new nodes with all the field_childs values available instead of taking them one by one.

I end up with titles like:

First node: Timmy, Jack, Jimmy, Sam, Hannah

Second node: Timmy, Jack, Jimmy, Sam, Hannah
etc.

Instead of:

First node: Timmy

Second node: Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself.

Inside the loop when you create a node the pattern used for the title needs to be from the **Replacement patterns for Current list item** section and in my case, it was the [list-item:title] (the title of the current referenced entity in the loop).